# [Python]Can't make Travis CI work. PATHs problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, travis-ci

This is my first time using Travis and "test" in general. 
I created a few test and now I want to add them to Travis but I'm having trouble with PATHs.

Here is what I have:

```
sheetmaker/
      html_builder.py
      constants.py
      sheetmaker.py
tests/
      test_html_builder.py
      data/
              test_html_constants.py
```

I manage to run `test_html_builder.py` and test are working in my pc. In short this is how I'm importing stuff in **test_html_builder.py**

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
from sheetmaker import html_builder
from data import test_html_constants
```

This works locally but Travis CI says:

- from sheetmaker import html_builder
- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sheetmaker'

What is the right way to import stuff? Here is the github project for more details: [github project!](https://github.com/cosme12/cheatsheet-maker/tree/develop)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd instead suggest working from the directory above `test_html_builder.py` and run `python -m tests.test_html_builder`, this'll give you a more realistic execution environment and will work in both local and travis-ci without mucking with `sys.path`.  [here's some additional reading about why you should almost always do this](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/wiki/PythonPathSadness)

Comment: You need an `__init__.py` in your sheetmaker directory.

Comment: @erip In my case I had a __init__.py file already in the directory that had the module I wanted to import and Travis still was unable to find it. I'll try to upload a video showing this.

Comment: @erip check this video out https://s3.amazonaws.com/mababio/travis_python_path.mp4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tons of research, I started printing `print(sys.path)` to find out where "I was working". From there I created an exception handler

```
try:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..')) #Works for local
    from sheetmaker import html_builder
    from data import test_html_constants
except:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.')) #Works for Travis CI
    from sheetmaker import html_builder 
    from data import test_html_constants
```

Is this the right way to import modules? No idea, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

@cosme12 I didn't try your solution, but I was able to fix the path issue by explicitly declaring the PYTHONPATH in the .travis.yml

sample .travis.yml:

```
sudo: false
language: python

python:
  - "3.6"

install:
  - export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd)/src/thermo
  - python3 setup.py install

script:
  - pytest -s
```

Just manually add the path that's missing to the .travis.yml and travis should work.

I like this solution because you don't need to alter your code, just the travis config file.